# Angular and html5 mode true

Tags: angularjs, express, heroku

I have an angular app built on top of [Angular-Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) with the add of [Express](http://linqed.eu/2014/10/07/deploying-angular-seed-to-heroku/) as a web server in order to make it works on Heroku.

Everything is working fine, but I need to introduce the html mode in order to get rid of the "#" symbol in the url. I read that I need some back-end modifications (because when I simply add the html mode, refreshing a page leads to 404 error) but I am not an expert of Node/Express so I don't have a clue on what to do.

Can you please guys help me out?

EDIT:

What I did until now:

Added this line in my angular route:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Added this line in my index.html head:

```
 <base href="/">
```

Now the css seems to work, but any other url does not!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue!

I had to change my express server with this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('app/index.html');
});

app.listen(3001);
```

After that I had to switch from the $cookies to Store directive, here's the [reference](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/issues/59)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use base url of html5 to make it works. you can get more info from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Maybe you missed this one from your head section of html.

```
<base href="/app/">
```

Comment: I added it but nothing changed. Every url I visit I get "Cannot get /url_name". On top of that the js/css is not loaded!

Edit: with <base href="/"> I can see the js/css but still no luck with the others url!

Comment: I understand. If you share your <head> section code then i could help you.
Definitely a settings problem.